Bayes Factor for two exact hypotheses on normally distributed data with unknown variance
Let's assume that the observations $x_i$ are normally distributed
$$
x_i \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)
$$
and that the variance $\sigma^2$ is unknown. The Bayes Factor to compare two point hypotheses on the mean value
$$
H_0: \mu=\mu_0, \sigma^2 \text{unknown}\\\\
H_1: \mu=\mu_1, \sigma^2 \text{unknown}
$$
is
$$
B_{01} = \frac{M(H_0 | \textbf{x})}{M(H_1 | \textbf{x})} 
       = \frac{\int L(\mu_0, \sigma | \textbf{x}) p(\sigma) d\sigma}
              {\int L(\mu_1, \sigma | \textbf{x}) p(\sigma) d\sigma} 
$$
where $M(H_i | \textbf{x})$ is the marginal likelihood, $L(\mu_i, \sigma | \textbf{x})$ is the joint likelihood and $p(\sigma)$ the prior distribution for the unknown parameter $\sigma$.
The joint likelihood function corresponds to the probability of the normally distributed  data given the mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$
$$
L(\mu, \sigma | \textbf{x}) = p(\textbf{x} | \mu, \sigma) = \prod_{i=1}^n f(x_i | \mu, \sigma)
$$
where $f(x_i | \mu, \sigma)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi} \sigma} e^{-\frac{(x_i-\mu)^2}{2 \sigma^2}}$ is the probability density function of the normal distribution
$N(\mu, \sigma^2)$.
It is known that the prior has a larger influence on the marginal likelihood and Bayes factor than on the posterior distribution (e.g. Rouder et al., 2009;
Lambert, 2018).
Questions:

Is there a prior $p(\sigma)$ that leads to a simple expression
for the marginal likelihood and/or the Bayes factor in this?
Does it make sense to use an improper prior such as $p(\sigma) = 1/\sigma$ ?
Is it not better to use prior such that its expected value corresponds
to the variance of the data $E_p[\sigma] = s^2$?
If there is no analytical expression for the marginal likelihood or
bayes factor, which algorithm (or R function) to use to compute the
marginal likelihood and the Bayes factor?

P.S.: I did several simulations using the scaled $\chi^2$ distribution $\text{scaled-}\chi^2(k,\theta)$ as prior for $\sigma$, which confirm that the choice of the parameter $k$ and $\theta$ can have a large effect on the Bayes factor. I can post these results to provide further motivation for the question and illustrate the underlying issue.
Update
I have looked at the effect of different non-informative priors on the Bayes factor. The priors are reported in following the table:

The priors are expressed as a function of the variance and of the standard deviation. The last column contains an analytical expression that corresponds to the marginal likelihood:
$$
L(\mu|\mathbf{x}) = \int_0^\infty L(\mu, \sigma^2 | \mathbf{x})
\pi_{\sigma^2}(\sigma^2) d \sigma^2
$$
or
$$
L(\mu|\mathbf{x}) = \int_0^\infty L(\mu, \sigma | \mathbf{x})
\pi_{\sigma}(\sigma) d \sigma
$$
The two integrals should give the same result (I was able to obtain an expression only for one prior).
The next figure plots the marginal likelihoods $L(\mu | x)$ for a small dataset with five observations: {-1, 3, -2, 1, -1}. The sample mean and sample standard deviation are $m=0$ and $s=2$ respectively.

Each panel corresponds to a different prior. I computed the marginal likelihoods numerically using both integrals (dashed blue and red lines). The black line in the third panel corresponds to the analytical expression (it overlaps the numerical results).
The next figure shows the effect of the prior on the Bayes Factor:
$$
B_{01} = \frac{L(\mu_0 | \textbf{x})}{L(\mu_1 | \textbf{x})} 
$$
for various alternative hypotheses $H_1: \mu_1 = m + k s$ (with $k$ ranging from -2.5 to 2.5) assuming $H_0: \mu_0 = m - s$. The likelihood ratio (LR) is also included.

The figure shows that the effect of the prior is important. For example, when $\mu_1 = m$, the Bayes factor varies from 0.39 to 0.09 (>300%)!  Interestingly, the effect of the prior does not decrease when the sample size increases (not shown here).
I am still interested to find analytical expressions for the marginal likelihood and Bayes factor for all priors in the table if they exist.  The large effect of the prior on the Bayes factor makes me very hesitant to use them, but I would appreciate any comment.

If you seek a simple form, you could try the conjugate distribution (inverse gamma on $\sigma^2$); I think it should lead to a relatively simple BF at least. But indeed yes, it does matter which prior you choose, even among ones that are supposedly "low information". IIRC Gelman has written some stuff about this sensitivity  (among others).


there are priors leading to closed form expressions; 2. using the same improper prior is considered as acceptable by many; 3. dependence on the data cancels consistency results; 4. there are specific algorithms for Bayes factors. (All of these points being thoroughly treated in Bayesian textbooks.)


I have looked at conjugate priors and found examples where the normal-inverse chi squared prior was used to compute the bayes factor when the alternative hypothesis is not exact ($\mu \sim N(\mu_0, \sigma_\mu)$) (e.g. Rouder et al. 2009). However, I could not find an example where an expression for the marginal likelihood or Bayes factor was derived when the prior was only an inverse gamma or inverse chi-squared distribution. Unfortunately, I am not good at integrating expressions.

Rouder et al. 2009 actually provides expressions for the so-called scaled JZS and scaled-information BFs but they apply to a situation when the alternative is not exact if I am not mistaken.

@xian. 2. I have read that 1/sigma is uniform on the log scale but I still have a problem with a prior that give so much weight to small value of sigma (to me, the sigma scale is the most natural when thinking of data). I was hoping that the choice of a prior would not affect the BF but my simulations did not confirm this.  3. I was not aware that it is bad practice to use the data (in a LRT, nuisance parameters can be replaced by their MLE if I am not mistaken).  As I am not a statistician, I would appreciate a pointer toward a book or reference that treats this case thoroughly.

When $\mu \sim N(\mu_0, \sigma_\mu)$ and $\sigma_\mu\downarrow 0$, you retrieve the case you are interested in.

See Berger & Pericchi (2004)

@xian.  I have looked at the effect of non-informative priors on the Bayes factor and updated the question to include the results. I derived an analytical expression for the marginal likelihood in one case but could not find similar expression for the Bayes factor in Berger & Pericchi (2004) or other references. Can you have another look at the question? Thank you.

A partial answer that reports the marginal likelihood $L(\mu, x)$ and Bayes factor $B_{01}$
when the prior defined over the variance is $\pi_{\sigma^2}(\sigma^2) =1/\sigma^2$.



Prior
Prior $\pi_{\sigma^2}(\sigma^2)$
Marginal likelihood $L(\mu, x)$
Bayes Factor




Uniform over $\sigma^2$
$1$




Uniform over $\sigma$
$\frac{1}{\sqrt{\sigma^2}} = \frac{1}{\sigma}$




Uniform over $\log(\sigma)$
$\frac{1}{\sigma^2}$
$(\pi A(\mu, \textbf{x}))^{-n/2} \Gamma(n/2)$
$\left(\frac{A(\mu_1|\textbf{x})}{A(\mu_0|\textbf{x})}\right)^{n/2}$


Jeffreys prior
$\frac{1}{\sigma^{2^{3/2}}}=\frac{1}{\sigma^3}$





where $\textbf{x} = \{x_1, \dots, x_n\}$ is a set of normally distributed observations, and
$$
BF_{01} = \frac{L(\mu_0, \textbf{x})}{L(\mu_1, \textbf{x})} \\
L(\mu, \textbf{x}) = \int_0^\infty L(\mu, \sigma^2| \textbf{x}) \pi_{\sigma^2}(\sigma^2) d\sigma^2
$$
and
$$
A(\mu, \textbf{x}) = SS_y + n(\mu-m)^2\\
SS_y = \sum_i (x_i - m)^2 \\
m = \frac{1}{n} \sum x_i
$$
The table is incomplete. I would like to know if there are similar analytical expressions for the marginal likelihood and Bayes factor for the other priors. The table includes
only non-informative priors but it would also be nice to extend it to informative prior for the variance such as the inverse scaled chi-squared distribution if there are analytical expressions for the corresponding marginal likelihoods and Bayes Factors.
